# Initial value problem using Laplace Transform

Tags: laplace-transform, initial-value-problems, inverse-laplace

I have to solve the IVP:
$$\begin{cases}
y''+by'-cy=1\\
y(0)=y_0\\
y'(0)=y'_0
\end{cases}$$

Suppose $$Y(s)=\frac{s^2+2s+1}{s^3+3s^2+2s}$$

We have to find $b,c,y_0$ and $y'_0$

I have found that:
$$(s^2+s+1)Y(s)-(s+1)y_0-y'_0=1/s$$

How do I proceed further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the given ODE $y''+by'-cy=1$, **your last line** should be
$$(s^2+bs-c)Y(s)-(s+b)y_0-y'_0=1/s$$
which implies
$$Y(s)=\frac{y_0s^2+(by_0+y'_0)s+1}{s^3+bs^2-cs}.$$
Now, by comparing it with $Y(s)=\frac{s^2+2s+1}{s^3+3s^2+2s}$, we are  able to find  $b$, $c$, $y_0$ and $y'_0$ easily:
$$b=3,c=-2, y_0=1, y'_0=-1.$$

Comment: thank you so much, found this method easy to understand

Answer (score 2):

You have that the Laplace transform of the solution $y(t) $ is $Y(s) $. So the inverse Laplace transform of $Y(s) $ gives us the solution $y(t) =\frac{e^{-2t}+1}{2}$. From this we can calculate $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0) =-1$. Now sustitute the expression of $y(t)$ in the equation and you'll get $$e^{-2t}(4-2b+c) -(2+c) =0.$$ Since $e^{-2t}$ and $1$ are linearly independent we Have that $b=3$ and $c=-2$.

Comment: understood it, thank you so much!